# jQuery Toggle not working on iPad?

Tags: jquery

I'm doing a toggle on a button (a link) to reveal a top panel, the panel slides down on the click of a button which adds a class to this, then the nav fades in when the panel is down.

This works fine on all browsers but on my iPad the removeclass doesn't remove?

```
$("header").css("margin-top", "-130px");
$("a#mainMenu").toggle(function() {
        $(this).addClass("navopen");
        $("header").animate({ marginTop: "0" }, 600);
        $("nav").delay(400).fadeIn(400);
        return false;
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass("navopen");
        $("nav").fadeOut(400);
        $("header").delay(300).animate({ marginTop: "-130px" }, 500);
});
```

Any help would be great.

Regards,

TJ

Comment: this functionality is normally wrapped around an eventhandler. I see no click or ontouch event that would trigger this.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas right, there is no trigger here. You should edit like this.

```
$("a.somelinkclass").click(function(){
 $("a#mainMenu").toggle(function() {
    $(this).addClass("navopen");
    $("header").animate({ marginTop: "0" }, 600);
    $("nav").delay(400).fadeIn(400);
    return false;
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("navopen");
    $("nav").fadeOut(400);
    $("header").delay(300).animate({ marginTop: "-130px" }, 500);
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I'm a bit lost as the "a#mainMenu" is the trigger button so I was to specify this as the click trigger then what element would I place in the reference for the toggle?